# Exporting High Quality TIFF Files on ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, geotiff-tiff, export, arcgis-10.5

I am currently working in ArcMap 10.5.1 and am wanting to export a Map as a TIFF file with increased resolution.  If I were to increase the quality of the image to anything above 96 DPI then the image will just appear blank after exporting.

Here are my current steps in ArcMap 10.5.1

Here are my current steps:

1)  File (On Upper left tool bar) => Export Map

2)  Chose my folder that I want the image saved in

3)  In the Options section.  I increase the Resolution by increasing the DPI

4)  Then I press save and the image is in my folder

The above steps only work if I leave the resolution at the default DPI (96 DPI).  If I were to increase that number, after the image is saved, it will just appear blank.  Do you know why this is happening? And do you know how I can create a high quality tiff file in ArcMap?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your graphics card or the graphics card drivers?  What happens if you export to JPG or PNG at high resolutions?

Comment: What have you chosen on the Format tab under options?

Comment: The reasoning for wanting a Tiff, is because I need it as a input for the "Export Training Data" feature that Esri provides, and later will be used in "Deep Learning in ArcGIS Pro".  But to anwser your question, it also appears blank in JPG and PNG.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I have left those credentials at default settings.  Color Mode: 240-bit True Color.  Compression: None.  Unchecked the Write GeoTIFF Tags.

Comment: You're using a version that is more than 6 years old... maybe update to 10.8.x? (ArcMap 10.5.1 was released in 2017 and generally ESRI products are well known for having HUGE amount of bugs). I didn't have that problem in 10.6.x - 10.8.x

Answer (score 0):

I know that its a work around, but have you considered migrating your project to ArcGIS Pro and then exporting from there. I have had some wonky things happen in ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro does some things a little better.

[ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro project Converion](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/analytics/analytics/migrate-your-content-to-arcgis-pro-2-1/)

[Export TIFF  from ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/overview/export-a-map-or-layout.htm#GUID-80764A31-87D3-4D2A-8894-8A27D76CB89F)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AvidDabbler I'll propose this idea.  The reason we're not currently going that route, is because we had issues getting Digital Globe ImageConnect to work in ArcGIS Pro.  Therefore we could not stream and view the imagery in Pro.

Comment: I tried exporting the Map from ArcMap and imported in Pro.  I was not able to view the images in ArcGIS Pro because they were linked to ImageConnect.  ImageConnect currently does not have any compatibility with pro, as they only have a beta version that I could not find, so I assume that its not open to the public.

Comment: are you getting any error notifications? You could try to check the error logs. arcgis pro=> <user>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\ArcGISPro\ArcToolbox\History arcmap => <user>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.6\ArcToolbox\History

Comment: My History Directory appears to be empty in both ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap.